# Openmp not parallelizing for loop, gives sequential execution

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, pthreads, openmp

I am trying to parallelize a for loop in my code base that should be embarrassingly parallel. However, Openmp is not doing so and rather is executing everything in sequential order. program complied using g++, std=c++11, I have executed a small program to ensure if openmp works or not, and it worked just fine.

The code block I am trying to parallelize is given below

```
void class_tmv::activate(class_tmv &result, const &a, const &b, const &c, const &d, const &e, f) const
    {
        result.clear();
        #pragma omp parallel for 
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < tms.size(); ++i)
        {
            class_TM tmTemp;
            tms[i].activate(tmTemp, a, b, c, d, e, f);
            result.tms[i] = tmTemp;
        }
    }
```

`Class_tmv` has class variable `tms`, that is essentially a vector of `Class_TM` objects. `Class_TM` has a method also named `activate` that gets called above, it is defined as

```
    inline void Class_TM::activate(Class_TM &result, const &a, const &b, const &c, const &d, const &e, f) const
    {
        
        result.clear();
        Class_TM tmTemp;

        if (condition_1)
        {
            this->S_T(tmTemp, a, b, c, d, e, f);
        }
        else if (condition_2)
        {
            this->T_T(tmTemp, a, b, c, d, e, f);
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "The activation fundtion can be parsed." << endl;
        }
        result = tmTemp;
    }
```

`S_T` and `T_T` are other methods in `class_TM`.

The issue I'm having is the overall execution of the system is completely sequential, and the loop I'm trying to parallelize isn't working.

Any suggestions on what may be going wrong are extremely helpful.
Any other solutions not related to openmp are also welcomed.

(This is my first time working on parallel applications)

Comment: Can you please share the command used to compile the code?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 3):

Did you use the `-fopenmp` flag when compiling your code?

Answer (score 2):

Your full code or more context on the command used to compile would be helpful, but here are some pointers in the meantime:

- As other answer mentioned, you should compile with `-fopenmp` or similar (depending on compiler). However, if you mention that you did a test and verified OpenMP worked correctly, then it's likely you did include that option and also the headers on your .c files.
- As it seems you are experiencing, if you compile with OpenMP #pragmas and the optimizer sees no way to parallelize your for, or it is not in the "Canonical Form", then it will not be optimized. The Canonical Form of a for loop, among other things, requires that the stopping criteria is fixed and does not change across iterations (in this case the `tms.size()`). If the call to `tms[i].activate()` modifies `tms`'s size, then that would not follow Canonical form and would not be optimized (or the subsequent calls to `S_T` and `T_T`) Check if this is your case on your context.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion guys read a bit more bout that and edited that part out of the answer :) @paleonix

Comment: The for loop is in canonical form for sure. There are definite stopping conditions and the `tms.size()` doesn't change during execution. I Saw possibilities of race conditions in the function calls. All the values were being passed by reference. I changed that so no race condition occurs in variables. But still no results in parallelizing.

Comment: @Harshang can you share the command used to compile the program? As well as your complete code so we can test?

Answer (score 0):

This adds to the Canonical Form point made by @DarkCygnus. Apart from checking the stopping criterion, check for thread safety. The calls to `S_T` and `T_T` should not have race conditions. They should be manipulating shared variables such that parallelization will still result in correct behavior.